# React js Typescript Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Hello I'm having this error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number>'.
```

this is a part of my code:

```
.
.
.
const[ idPadre, setIdPadre ] = useState<number>(0);
.
.
.

<select 
       onChange={ (e) => setIdPadre( e.target.value ) }
       value={ idPadre }
>
<option value="">Select...</option>
       {data.map((item) => {
                            return <option key={item.id}
                                    value={ item.id }
                            >{item.description}</option>
                            })}                                
</select>
```

so, I'm adding data from file json and I want that select an item and value get id.

Comment: `setIdPadre( e.target.value )` the value `e.target.value` potentiolly is a string not a `number` as you set in your `useState<number>(0);`. Either ParseInt it or set `useState` to `string` not a `number` or if you want to accept both string and numbers then do `useState<number | string>(0);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is pretty descriptive. You cannot pass parameter of type `string` into the useState hook which expects number.

You're calling the `setIdPadre` hook with the `e.target.value` variable, which is a string.

What you can do instead is convert the value into a number:

```
{ (e) => setIdPadre( parseInt(e.target.value) ) }
```

Comment: hey @val, I am getting a similar error when trying to use a JSON file, something like this:

export const CTASection = () => {
  const {t, i18n} = useTranslation( {keyPrefix: ("homepage.ctaSection")} )